Combining interpolate and match expression with map.addLayer()
I'm trying to combine an interpolate expression with a match expression (I followed this post). So I have the following code which works as expected:
map.current.addLayer({
  id: 'environment-items',
  type: 'symbol',
  source: 'environment-items',
  layout: {
    (...)
    'icon-size': [
      'interpolate',
      ['exponential', 2],
      ['zoom'],
      0,
      0.05 * Math.pow(2, 0 - viewport.baseZoom),
      24,
      0.05 * Math.pow(2, 24 - viewport.baseZoom),
    ],
  }
});

So I tried to make an equivalent by adding a match expression, like this:
map.current.addLayer({
  id: 'environment-items',
  type: 'symbol',
  source: 'environment-items',
  layout: {
    (...)
    'icon-size': [
        "interpolate",
        ["exponential", 2], 
        ["zoom"],
        0, 
          ["match", ['get', 'Type'],
              ...environment_items.flatMap(({ name, size }) => [
                name,
                0.05 * Math.pow(2, 0 - viewport.baseZoom),
              ]),
              0.05 * Math.pow(2, 0 - viewport.baseZoom),
          ],
        24,
          ["match", ['get', 'Type'],
            ...environment_items.flatMap(({ name, size }) => [
              name,
              0.05 * Math.pow(2, 24 - viewport.baseZoom),
            ]),
              0.05 * Math.pow(2, 24 - viewport.baseZoom),
          ],
      ],
  }
});

But the result is absolutely not the same. So in my case, I need to use match to adjust the size of each "Type" of my layer and I need to use interpolate to give a fixed size based on the zoom level (so that if you zoom out, for example, the icons shrink). I can't find a solution and I don't understand why there is a difference between the two codes. Thanks for your help!
So I expect the result to be able to give a size based on the Type while still having the option to set a fixed size.
